# Mimosa tree split...can it become a tree again

Tags: trees

Our Mimosa tree split for a few years due to the weather and we finally had to cut it down to a stump. Can it grow into a tree from the stump? There are tons of shoots coming out from it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pick the best 3 (or so) shoots, cut the rest of the "ton" of shoots, repeat cutting of new shoots every few weeks until it gets the idea. If you want a single trunk, remove the worst/weakest of the 3 (or so,) let the remaining ones grow for a while, and continue remove the weakest stem until you are down to one.